# How do I create an exponentiated double value?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my code, but it's not compiling right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        double x=input.nextDouble();
        x = (xe3) + (xe2) + x + 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `xe3` is invalid,you need to use the right function to do it

Comment: did you mean pow(x,3) + pow(e,2) or x*1000 + x*100 ? these are different things

Comment: `x = Math.pow(x, 3) + Math.pow(x, 2) + x + 1`

Answer (score 3):

`xe3` and `xe2` are invalid expression,you can use `Math.pow()` instead

So change

```
x=(xe3)+ (xe2)+ x + 1;
```

to

```
x = Math.pow(x, 3) + Math.pow(x, 2) + x + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks lucumt, I seem to have misinterpreted the use of exponentials.